# How to use find and replace wildcards in SSMS?

Tags: regex, wildcard, ssms, ssms-2012

So I have something like:

```
Price1
Price2
Price3
```

And I'd like to do a Find and Replace on them so the end result is this:

```
COALESCE(Price1, 0)
COALESCE(Price2, 0)
COALESCE(Price3, 0)
```

I tried using this:

```
Find what: Price.
Replace with: coalesce(Price., 0)
```

The result is:

```
COALESCE(Price.,0)
```

I've gone into Find Options and checked "Use: Regular Expressions".

What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace Coalesce(Price.,0) with Coalesce(\0,0) and you'll be good to go.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use capturing groups and in the replace use the capture group content.

You can use this regex:

```
(Price\d+)
```

**[Working demo](http://regex101.com/r/rT8cR0/1)**

Check the substitution section the capture group content usage...

[image]

Comment: Doesn't work in Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 2012 (11.0.2100.60). This works: **find:** `(Price[0-9]+)` **replace:** `COALESCE(\0, 0)`.